# How much cpu time per core?

Tags: vb6, cpu-usage, com+, cpu-cores

Please help me understand this.

I have an STA VB6 application. It is running on the same virtual server as a .net web application. There are two cores on that server. To measure performance of the .net application, i record cpu utilization which is around 30%. The VB6 application uses about 20% cpu. It is also locking the core for some time while it makes out of apartment calls to the database.

If the VB6 application spends 1 minute on an out of apartment call, can i assume that the core is completely locked for one minute? In other words, can i assume that each core provides one hour of "cpu time" per hour for the VB6 application? So if i have two cores, can i also say that this setup provides 120 minutes of "cpu time" per hour?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Nobody locks a core, ever. You are confusing Threads with Cores.

The thread *might* (but probably won't) block for a minute during a remote call. But a Core is not tied to running only one thread, or it would be impossible for modern Windows (Windows 95 and newer) to work at all. Windows needs to be able to service *hundreds* of processes simultaneously, with as little as one single core.

On a typical session, the kernel will suspend *dozens, or hundreds of times per second* some or all of your process's threads, and assign each core to do something else. Eventually, your thread will come back to live - maybe on the same core, maybe on a different one.

In particular a thread making a remote call is typically placed in a "wait state", which means the kernel will not assign a Core to the thread *at all* until the remote call completes.

*(several approximations taken, but that's the gist of it)*

> can i assume that each core provides one hour of "cpu time" per hour for the VB6 application? So if i have two cores, can i also say that this setup provides 120 minutes of "cpu time" per hour?

No. The only practical way to find out how much cpu time a process consumes is to look at its performance counters. It will most certainly be a lot less than 1 hr of CPU time per elapsed hour. For it to be even close to an hour of CPU time per elapsed hour, you would have to end up with an aggregate nearly 100% CPU utilization (for the VB6 process on its own). For example, it would be something like 48% per core on a two-core system, all consumed by the VB6 process, or some such.

Additionally, for an STA thread like what VB6 uses, adding cores will makes no difference whatsoever (barring an multithreaded COM object that does significant work outside the STA) on the amount of (elapsed, not CPU) time the process takes to run.

Adding CPU cores almost never gives any increase on beneficial CPU time consumption by a process, because the amount of usual CPU time needed to complete a task doesn't change just because you have extra silicon nearby.

But I think we're both missing something. What is it exactly that you are trying to find out? I don't know what is your real question, but I bet that "cpu time" is not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is tagged as COM+ so you need to consider how COM+ manages threads for components.

The core should not be "locked".  And neither should threads in COM+ (depending on how you define locked) since one thread can service multiple requests.

That said, an STA COM+ component making long (60 seconds!) out of apartment calls in COM+ is a recipe for performance problems.

Basically, the COM+ STA thread pool binds up to 5 activities to each STA thread. When you make an out of apartment call COM+ allows other requests to be serviced as another activity on the STA thread. This can happen for up to 5 activities (per thread). Also once control has been given to another activity the original activity cannot regain control until the second activity is complete. Under heavy load and/or if the calls are "long running" then the time for the first activity to complete is the sum of the times for all of the other activities (on the thread) to complete. This can kill your performance.

The best article on this is [Avoid Long Running Method Calls from a Single-Threaded Apartment (STA)](http://blog.yezhucn.com/dncomser/PortingWinNTApps_MTStoCOM.htm#portingwinntapps_mtstocom_avoid_long_running_method_calls_from_a_single_threaded_apartment).  I can't find the original Microsoft article so I'm linking to this third party archived version.